# Autenticar con certificado digital para usar SOAP con PHP

Tags: php, soap, openssl

necesito convertir una clave encriptada que me dieron formato pkcs#10 para hacer uso de un SOAP

El formato de la clave encriptada que me devolvió la solicitud del certificado digital es esta.

```
BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----

Contenido del certificado......

-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

semejante a este. Entonces quisiera poder autenticarme con esta clave para usar el SOAP

Le agradecería alguna guia. Gracias

```
    <?php 

 $url = "https://efactura.dgi.gub.uy:6470/ePrueba/ws_personaGetActEmpresarialPrueba?wsdl";


  $client = new SoapClient($url);

//   para depurar

 $client = new SoapClient($url, array("trace" => 1, "soap_version" => SOAP_1_2));

 $fcs = $client->__getFunctions();
 $types = $client->__getTypes();



 $res  =  $client -> Execute( array ( 'Rut'  =>  '217061580012' ));
 echo '<pre>';
 print_r($res);
 echo '</pre>';
 die();
  echo  "tendria que sacar el rut:" ;
  echo  $res -> GetElementSymbolResult ;
```

No sabria como autenticarlo. Rste certificado me lo dieron de la siguiente manera:

Me pidieron una clave privada y yo genere un archivo clave.csr, copie la clave encriptada y se las mande en la solicitud del certificado digital. Y ellos me devolvieron esa clave que mostre anteriormente. No sabria de que manera autenticarme sabiendo que tengo dos claves = la mia que genere y la de ellos que generaron con la mia.

la clave que yo les envie a ellos fue un archivo que genere con openssl

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----
ContenidoDelCSR.....
-----END CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----
```

copie el cifrado y se los envie.

Tengo la guia del SOAP pero es una guia para usarla mediante un interface SOAP

https://www.efactura.dgi.gub.uy/files/web-services-consulta-de-rut?es

Comment: Agrega el codigo que ya intentaste, asi no se pueden sugerir correcciones o agregar comentarios

Comment: @MiguelZarate Gracias por tu comentario, re formule la pregunte con mas informacion. Gracias

Comment: Amigo, el contenido de el CSR y de tu certificado NO se publican en ninguna parte :)  Mi recomendación, tras encontrar la respuesta a tu pregunta, es que vuelvas a generar el certificado

Comment: @Alfabravo gracias por la recomendacion. No es el contenido real.